# Issue in counting relationships for nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, twitter4j, relationships

I've got a Neo4j database in which hashtags and tweets are stored.
Every tweet has a `topic` property, which defines the topic it belongs to.
If I run the following query, I get the most popular hashtags in the db, no matter the topic:

```
MATCH (h:Hashtag)
RETURN h.text AS hashtag, size( (h)<--() ) AS degree ORDER BY degree DESC
```

I'd like to get the most popular tags for a single topic.
I tried this:

```
MATCH (h:Hashtag)<--(t:Tweet{topic:'test'})
RETURN h.text AS hashtag, size( (h)<--(t) ) AS degree ORDER BY degree DESC
```

this

```
MATCH (h:Hashtag)
RETURN h.text AS hashtag, size( (h)<--(t:Tweet{topic:'test'}) ) AS degree ORDER BY degree DESC
```

while the next one takes forever to run

```
MATCH (h:Hashtag), (t:Tweet)
WHERE t.topic='test'
RETURN h.text AS hashtag, size( (h)<--(t) ) AS degree ORDER BY degree DESC
```

What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cypher, when you return the results of an aggregation function you get an implicit "group by" with whatever you are returning alongside the aggregation function. `SIZE()` is not an aggregation (so you'll get the size of the pattern for each row without the group by/aggregation), but `COUNT()` is:

```
MATCH (t:Tweet {topic:'test'})-->(h:Hashtag)
RETURN h, COUNT(*) AS num ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 10
```

This query is counts of `Tweet` nodes, grouped by `Hashtag`.

Comment: Thank you William, I'll try as soon as possible. By the way, is this an optimal solution - speaking about performance - or will it lead to poor performances?